# Group similar items

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, grouping

Here is my table structure with data

```
    id     actor_id   created_at              updated_at 

    729    80         2012-09-10 17:05:59    2012-09-10 17:05:59
    731    80         2012-09-10 17:04:02    2012-09-10 17:04:02
    725    139        2012-09-06 13:59:08    2012-09-06 13:59:08
    724    76         2012-09-06 11:31:30    2012-09-06 11:31:30
    723    29         2012-09-06 09:40:22    2012-09-06 09:40:22
    719    29         2012-09-06 09:24:02    2012-09-06 09:24:02
    811    80         2012-09-02 17:05:59    2012-09-10 17:05:59
    812    80         2012-09-01 17:04:02    2012-09-10 17:04:02
```

This is the result of

```
SELECT  `te`.`id`, te.actor_id, te.created_at, te.created_at
FROM `timeline_events` AS te
ORDER BY 
    te.created_at DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

I need group it by actor_id and created_at

Here is what i need in the end

```
    id    actor_id     created_at          updated_at             count

    729    80       2012-09-10 17:05:59    2012-09-10 17:05:59     2
    725    139      2012-09-06 13:59:08    2012-09-06 13:59:08     1
    724    76       2012-09-06 11:31:30    2012-09-06 11:31:30     1
    723    29       2012-09-06 09:40:22    2012-09-06 09:40:22     2
    812    80       2012-09-10 17:04:02    2012-09-10 17:04:02     2
```

Can someone guide me how to do this?

Many thanks in advance

**UPD** To simplify i will put another example

So say i have next rows

```
1                                             1 (count: 2)
1
3                                             3 (count: 1)
4
4     => after magic function it should be    4 (count: 2)
1
1                                             1 (count: 3)
1
6                                             6 (count: 2)
6
4                                             4 (count 3)
4
4
```

So it should split by groups.

**UPD 2**
I need this query for rendering timeline. Right now it show all info what user did, but i need group it.

Before

- user1 upload photo
- user1 changed information
- user2 updated bio
- user3 uploaded photo
- user3 updated bio
- user1 update bio

After

- user1 uploadd photo and changed infomarion
- user2 updated bio
- user3 uploaded photo and updated bio
- user1 updated bio

Comment: Good question, this stumps a lot of people in my experience. Here's a link to a similar query: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514943/php-mysql-order-by-two-columns

Comment: What aggregate function do you want to use with the field `id`? for example why do you want to get the ` 729    80 ` not `731    80 `??

Comment: @MahmoudGamal id is not important is this query. This query for grouping similar events(made by one user) in timeline

Comment: @ThomasWright thank you for the link.
But they try to order data but i need group it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution by myself

Here is the query

```
SET @i = 0;
SELECT
    COUNT(`wrapper`.`id`) AS 'count',
    GROUP_CONCAT(`wrapper`.`type` SEPARATOR ',') as 'types'
FROM (
    SELECT  
        @prev := (
            SELECT prev_te.actor_id
            FROM `timeline_events` AS prev_te
            WHERE prev_te.created_at > te.created_at
            ORDER BY prev_te.created_at ASC
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS 'prev_actor_id',
        IF(
            @prev = te.`actor_id` OR @prev IS NULL, 
            @i, 
            @i := @i + 1
        ) AS 'actor_id_group',
        `te`.*
    FROM `timeline_events` AS te
    ORDER BY 
        te.created_at DESC, 
        te.id DESC
) AS `wrapper`
GROUP BY `wrapper`.`actor_id_group`
LIMIT 10
```

And here is [the proof link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1c32/2) ;-)

[This website](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php) really helped me

I am using wrapper for grouping purpose, because mysql didn't group by variables, if someone know better solution, please let me know

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be what you are trying to do:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.actor_id,
  max(created_at) created_at,
  updated_at,
  t2.total
from yourtable t1
left join
(
  select count(*) total, date(created_at) dt, actor_id
  from yourtable
  group by actor_id, date(created_at)
) t2
  on t1.actor_id = t2.actor_id
  and date(t1.created_at) = t2.dt
group by  t1.actor_id, date(t1.created_at)
order by t1.created_at desc
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcb18/17)

I am grouping by `actor_id` and the date using the [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function

Comment: Thanks, very similar. But why it didn't group last two columns(where actor_id is 80)

Comment: Maybe it's my fault, because i didn't exaplain correct
So it should not use created_at for group, it should sort by this field only, but group by actor_id

Comment: @neimo0o I did `group by` the `created_at` field in both the subquery and the outer one. I just applied the `DATE()` function to it to return the date part only and strip the time

Comment: you group by created_at field, but i do not need it.
I need group by similar fields, smth [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478070/how-to-group-consecutive-similar-items-of-a-collection)

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your requirements then.  If you do not `group by created_at` then you will return the total `count` for the actor...so for your sample data `actor_id = 80` will have a `count` of 4, is that what you want?

Comment: we should split results by group. When actor_id changed, mean that start another gruop

Comment: see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478070/how-to-group-consecutive-similar-items-of-a-collection)

Comment: i have added another example, maybe it will help

Comment: @neimo0o since you found the answer, you should post it and then accept it.  It will help future visitors.  Glad you figured it out. I neve got the chance the go back and try to redo it. :)

Comment: thanks for the tip. I am new in stackoverflow(in author role)

Answer (score 0):

Add `GROUP BY actor_id` before `order by` clause.

Latest edit: 
`select distinct actor_id, count(actor_id), created_at from actors group by actor_id 
order by created_at desc;`

Comment: But What aggregate function to use with the field `id` and other fields that are not in the group by clause?

Comment: @sweettea if i add GROUP BY it will group by all ids, but i need to split by groups (i have added anohter example)

Comment: try ORDER BY te.created_at DESC, te.actor_id. This will order by created_at first, then by actor_id.

Comment: @sweettea but i need group them, not just order.

Comment: try the latest edit from my answer above: `select distinct actor_id, count(actor_id), created_at from actors group by actor_id 
order by created_at desc;`

Comment: @sweettea thanks for help, but unfortunately this is not what i need. I have found [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12474091/1078179)

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT  `te`.`id`, te.actor_id, te.created_at, te.updated_at ,
>   COUNT(*) FROM `timeline_events` AS te GROUP BY  te.actor_id,
>   te.created_at ORDER BY 
>       te.created_at DESC
>       LIMIT 10

Comment: This is not correct because the field `te.id` is not in the group by clause nor in an aggregate function

Comment: Yes, this is not what i need, because i do not need all ids group under one row