# LINQ - Merge list elements retaining order (functional thinking)

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have a list of sql statements as

```
List<IStatement>
```

- UPDATE a SET a.col1=1 FROM tableA a
- UPDATE a SET a.col2=2 FROM tableA a
- UPDATE a SET a.col3=3 FROM tableA a
- SELECT a.Col1,a.Col2,a.Col3 FROM tableA a
- UPDATE b SET b.col1=1 FROM tableB b
- UPDATE b SET b.col2=2 FROM tableB b
- SELECT b.Col1,b.Col2 FROM tableB b

Salient classes include:

- SelectStatement : IStatement
- UpdateStatement : IStatement

The UpdateStatement has a

- GetFrom method which returns a From clause
- GetSets method which returns an IEnumerable
- AddSet method which adds a new Set expression to the existing Sets

I have an IsEqualTo extension method to compare From clauses

I am trying to merge the update statements into a single update statement using the Linq Aggregate operator whilst retaining order so that the final list would be .

- UPDATE a SET a.col1=1,a.col2=2,a.col3=3 FROM tableA a
- SELECT a.Col1,a.Col2,a.Col3 FROM tableA a
- UPDATE b SET b.col1=1,b.col2=2 FROM tableB b
- SELECT b.Col1,b.Col2 FROM tableB b

I was thinking of using aggregates to try and do this  - thus far my code is

```
Dim mergeUpdates = Function(statements As IList(Of IStatement), statement As IStatement)

                       If statements.Count = 0 Then Return statements.AddItem(statement)
                       If Not TypeOf statement Is UpdateStatement Then Return statements.AddItem(statement)

                       Dim u = DirectCast(statement, UpdateStatement)
                       Dim t = (From st In statements
                               Where TypeOf st Is UpdateStatement
                               Let uSt = DirectCast(st, UpdateStatement)
                               Where uSt.GetFrom.IsEqualTo(u.From)
                               Select uSt).First.AddSet(u.Set)

                       Return statements.AddItem(t)

                   End Function

 Return statements.Aggregate(New List(Of IStatement), Function(ss, s) mergeUpdates(ss, s)))
```

but now I'm not sure whether Linq Aggregate is the right way to do it. (I know the above is incomplete)

I'd be grateful of any pointers to the correct (FP) way of doing this.

Comment: You tagged this c#. Are you interested in c# answers as well as VB? Also, to solve this in a functional way, you will probably want something different than `AddSet`. Functional programming avoids side-effect and modifications to existing objects. So you need a way to create a new statement given a number of set clauses and a from clause.

Comment: @HugoRune - thx ... yes ... C# or VB, thx. re AddSet - point taken. Perhaps I need a CreateUpdate which takes Sets, a From and a Where etc etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will want to group related update statements together:

```
var groupedStatements = statements
       .GroupBy(s=>new {IsUpdate= (s is UpdateStatement), From=s.GetFrom()});
```

GroupBy will group related update statements, even if they are not consecutive in your list. If you only want to group consecutive statements, you will need an alternative to GroupBy like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2528167/145999) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138361.aspx).

This assumes that all IStatements have a GetFrom(), if not you will need some trickery with the `?` operator. Also, it requires that the `From` class implements IEquatable, to allow the GroupBy operator to check for identical from clauses. If it does not, you will need to convert the from clause  to a string or something, to allow comparison.

Then you combine the elements of each update group, and leave the other groups unchanged

```
var combinedStatements = groupedStatements
        .SelectMany(group=>group.Key.IsUpdate 
            ? Enumerable.Repeat<IStatement>(new UpdateStatement (group.Key.From, group.Select(s=>s.GetSets())),1)
            : group.Select(s=>s);
```

Here you need a way to create a new UpdateStatement, like a constructor that takes a from clause and an IEnumerable of Set clauses. SelectMany collapses the resulting list of list of statements into a single list of statements. Note that Enumerable.Repeat(s,1) is used to create a new IEnumerable with just one element.